# Search for non-zero positive integers in a string using regex (python re)

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to run this code, to extract the non-zero positive integers from a string in Python:

```
#python code 
import re
positive_patron = re.compile('[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+')
string = '''esto si esta en level 0 y extension txt LEVEL0.TXT  
            2 4 5 6 -12  -43  1 -54s esto si esta en 1 pero es 
            txt  69 con extension txt y profunidad 2'''
print positive_patron.findall(string)
```

This gives the output `['0', '0', '2', '4', '5', '6', '12', '43', '1', '54', '1', '69', '2']`

However, I don't want to match 0 or negative numbers, and I want my output as `int`s, like this: `[2,4,5,6,1,1,69,2]`.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to be able to match `float` (numbers with a decimal point) values? From your example, it wouldn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: decimal numbers too

Answer (score 4):

Use the word boundary escape sequence `\b`, so it won't match a number that has other alphanumeric characters around it. Also use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prohibit a leading `-`.

```
positive_patron = re.compile(r'\b(?<!-)\d*\.?\d+\b')
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/PA0yGe/2)

To skip `0`, do that with a filter after using the regexp.

```
numbers = positive_patron.findall(string)
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers if x != '0']
```

Comment: for me this didn't work for decimal numbers like 123.012

Comment: The required non-zero digit should probably be before the `.`. Do you need to allow `.123` also?

Comment: It's probably easiest to just filter `0` out after doing the regexp.